# Next Auth: Deployed code redirecting me to localhost on login

Tags: next.js, next-auth

As the title suggests - I have a nextjs application that works absolutely fine locally - However, now I've deployed it to a dev environment, something really weird is happening.

I've deployed my application to a dev environment, and set my `NEXTAUTH_URL` Environment Variable to my development domain `dev.mydomain.com`.  However when I login it redirects me to `localhost:3000` .  The weird thing is, if I have my local server running, and I change the port it runs on to say `:4000`, the actual website redirects me to `localhost:4000`... It's like it knows where my code is running locally with no reference to it?

Does anyone know what's going on here?  I'm very confused - There's no reference to localhost in my codebase whatsoever, never mind the specific ports!

Comment: if you are are using Vercel, make sure, you are setting environment in production/preview. This can also be due to caching so be sure to clear your cache or use a different browser

Comment: Nick have you solved this problem by specifying "site"? It doesn't work for me...

Comment: @reallyWannaCryIfNOTGetAnswer I managed to resolve this by manually adding the NEXTAUTH_URL env var to my Dockerfile.  That was the only way I managed to get this working!

Comment: @reallyWannaCryIfNOTGetAnswer u gotta add NEXTAUTH_URL 
else it'll default to localhost

Comment: if using vercel do this; In my case in vercel just added this in project settings environemtn variable

```
# production development
NEXTAUTH_URL= https://next-auth-gamma.vercel.app
```

**Here is reference**
[how to setup production nextjs](https://medium.com/frontendweb/how-to-set-up-the-next-auth-library-for-development-and-production-in-nextjs-103e9e4e9691)

Answer (score 20):

Be sure to add `NEXTAUTH_URL` to your env variable config on your cloud server.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution check your Auth Providor settings.
In my case, I use Github Provider and forgot to change my github oAuth App settings. Change two settings Home Url & callback url to your hosted base domain.

for example:

http://localhost:3000/  ->   http://yourdomain.com/

Same for callback option.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSpeX.png)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue on next 13.2. The problem was that I put my route handler into app/api folder, and it was working perfect on dev, but not on prod. So if anyone facing this issue on next 13+, make sure that your route handler is in pages/api/auth folder

Comment: This is not a real solution, nor a workaround, this is avoiding the issue completely, most of the time people want to move completely to the App router, so no sense in going back to the Pages router just for the authentication...

Answer (score 3):

Just incase you are deploying to AWS Amplify and after specifying NEXTAUTH_URL in your environment variables it still doesn't work, you need to edit the build specification file so that it makes your env variables available on the server side runtime.

Simply add this to your build command

> "- env | grep -e NEXTAUTH_ >> .env.production"

See more here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-environment-variables.html

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to include "site" as a key in the object you pass to NextAuth, with the value of your environmental variable. For example:

`NextAuth({site: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL, providers: [...] })`

Comment: Even if there is no reference to localhost on your codebase whatsoever, NextAuth.js uses localhost:3000 as their default for all redirects and callbacks.

Comment: I don't see the site option in the NextAuth object, anything has changed recently?

Comment: It's not there by default you must type it out yourself. @MacFly For some reason i recall not being able to find the site property on the nextauth documentation but I learned about it on some logrocket article

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to add the site to your configuration of your NextAuth instance because I believe it redirects to localhost:3000 by default.

Comment: Do you know where and how to add this one exactly?

Comment: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to redeploy your app after setting your environment variable NEXTAUTH_URL.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and tried different things. It worked for me by just adding the NEXTAUTH_URL in my docker file of next.js 13 application. Like below

```
# Set the environment variable NEXTAUTH_URL in docker
ENV NEXTAUTH_URL="https://www.example.com/"
```