# Error UnknownAction: Cannot parse action at /api/auth/session

Tags: javascript, next-auth, qwik

I after update `package.json`encountered this error in the project

pacage.json changes
[image]

I get this error when I run the project:

[image]

```
import { serverAuth$ } from '@builder.io/qwik-auth'
import type { Provider } from '@auth/core/providers'
import Keycloak from '@auth/core/providers/keycloak'

export const { onRequest, useAuthSession, useAuthSignin, useAuthSignout } = serverAuth$(
    ({ env }) => ({
        secret: env.get("AUTH_SECRET"),
        trustHost: true,
        callbacks: {
            async session({
                session,
                token,
            }) {
                session.user.guid = token.sub
                return session
            }
        },
        providers: [
   
        ] as Provider[],
    })
);
```

Answer (score 9):

With `next-auth@5.0.0-beta-9`, I get it to work by setting the `NEXTAUTH_URL={host}/api/auth`

Comment: after pulling my hair off for long time, finally this worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using some Next.js versions (such as 14.0.3) along with AUTH_URL variable may cause some other types of errors

[TypeError: next_dist_server_web_exports_next_request__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a constructor](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/9922#issuecomment-1929347331)

After hours of searching I recommend using packages with the following versions

[image: Next.js and Next-Auth versions]

Some people suggests not using AUTH_URL variable, that is going to cause callback url mismatch when you deploy your application

[Next Auth: Deployed code redirecting me to localhost on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71109710/next-auth-deployed-code-redirecting-me-to-localhost-on-login)

If you also have a Dockerfile, do not forget to set env variables in it

```
ENV AUTH_URL=https://www.yourdomain.com/api/auth
```